# Range of substring in string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, substring

Is the a way to get the NSRange of an NSString in an NSString?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you look in the documentation?

NSString has the following method:

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString
```

The [NSString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:) at developer.apple.com says of this method:

> Finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string within the receiver.

Comment: Oops. That should have been obvious. Thank you!

Comment: Also note that there are some other methods that do largely the same, but the one I mentioned is the most basic one. The documentation explains the differences.

Answer (score -3):

You're making this up, right? Or is there some hidden clue in your question that makes `rangeOfString:` the wrong answer?

Comment: I'm so so sorry... I really didn't see that method. Thank you!